# fractional product or sum over real finite indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

Given a series $x_i$ where $i$ is an integer, we can define
$$
f(n)=\prod_{i}^n x_i
$$
I am wondering if there is a way to make extend $n$ into reals? $n$ might still be finite but could be rational or irrational numbers.

Equivalently if I take a $log$ on both sides, I am also asking is there a natural way to extend the sum
$$
g(n)=\sum_{i}^n y_i
$$
such that $n\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: It depends on what $x_i$ is. For example, if $x_i=i$, then $f(n)=n!$. This is well defined even for noninteger $n$.

Comment: @IraeVid That is a good example! Is there a general recipe for this generalization?

Comment: As I've said, it depends on what $x_i$ is. If $x_i=\{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2,\dots\}$ then no.

Comment: I guess if $i$ only takes values in the positive integers, you may generalized as $g(t)=\sum_{i\leq t}x_i$. Possible downside, the resulting function is far from being continuous.